# Visual Studio Team Services и Branch Policy, установленные через API

Tags: visual-studio

Я добавляю через Visual Studio Team Services API некоторые политики на ветку, например, список требуемых ревьюеров и минимальное количество аппрувов (api-version = 2.1-preview). Они применяются к ветке - при создании пул-реквеста на эту ветку отображаются установленные мной ограничения. Но в Web-интерфейсе Branch Policy они не отображаются. Кто-нибудь знает, почему веб-интерфейс их не отображает?

Answer (score 0):

Причина оказалось в том, что при вызове API в параметре `scope` я указывала `repositoryId` как `null`.

После того, как в этом параметре был указан ид репозитория, в котором находится ветка, в web-интерфейсе всё отобразилось. Запрос, решающий мою проблему имел подобный вид.

URL:

```
POST https://{instance}/defaultcollection/{project}/_apis/policy/configurations?api-version={version}
```

BODY:

```
{
  "isEnabled": true,
  "isBlocking": false,
  "type": {
    "id": "fa4e907d-c16b-4a4c-9dfa-4906e5d171dd"
  },
  "settings": {
    "minimumApproverCount": 1,
    "creatorVoteCounts": false,
    "scope": [
      {
        "repositoryId": PASTE_REPOSITORY_GUID_HERE,
        "refName": "refs/heads/some_branch",
        "matchKind": "exact"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```